# Javascript, how can I synchronously call function every second in the loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, callback

I am having hard time to make it synchronous work in the loop using async/await. 
What my small showChart does is to request 10 items from server and plot it on the server using plotly. 
In order to make it like it is coming in every second I like to put some sleep time ideally 1000 ms exact. However, it seems like that console.log printout every second but drawChart function is not called every second but shows everything at the last minute. How can I make it to draw every second? 
Thank you in advance ~~!!

```
/**
 * data comes with { status: '' , message:{ result : [{point:''}, {point:''} ...]}} in json format.  
**/
async function  showChart(url, nextPage ){
        let requestUrl  = url+nextPage;
        let resposne = await fetch(requestUrl);
        let data = await resposne.json();
        data = data.message.result;
        let points = await data.map(e=>e.point);
        console.log(fp1Deltas);
        const num =  fp1Deltas.map(  async delta =>{
           delay(1000);
           // await sleep (1000);
           drawChart(delta);
           console.log( delta);
         });
        console.log('done');       
    }

    const sleep = ms=>{
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

 const delay = ( ms)  => {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start;
            while( end < start + ms ){
                end = new Date().getTime();
            }
    };

    const  drawChart = point =>{

        Plotly.extendTraces('chart1', {
            y: [
                 [point]
            ]
        }, [0]);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Plotly.plot('chart1', [{
            y: [],
            type: 'line'
        }]);
        showChart(requestLocation, page);
        // fetchData(requestLocation,page);

    }); // end of document ready
```

Comment: You basically never want a function like that `delay` function. (The `sleep` one is okay.)

Comment: The `await` in `await data.map(e=>e.point);` makes no sense

Comment: Yes. ```await``` does not make sense in this particular example. I was thinking about the case there are lots of data coming in I need to process it. so it requires some time to wait until it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop through `fplDeltas` and call `drawChart` with each delta, separated by a second, you can do it like this:

```
// So we skip the `sleep` the first time
let first = true;
for (const delta of fplDeltas) {
    // Sleep on all but the first
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        await sleep(1000);
    }
    // Draw the chart
    drawChart(delta);
}
```

Since that's in an `async` function, the `await sleep(1000)` (note: **not** `delay`, your promise-based `sleep`) yields to the browser allowing it to do any drawing, etc.

Here's a simple example just adding a DOM element in `drawChart`:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function example() {
    const fplDeltas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let first = true;
    for (const delta of fplDeltas) {
        // Sleep on all but the first
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            await sleep(1000);
        }
        // Draw the chart
        drawChart(delta);
    }
}

function drawChart(delta) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = delta;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

(async () => {
    try {
        await example();
        console.log("Done");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error:", e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: *(Doh! If you don't see the live example, hit refresh -- I had a silly logic error prior to adding the live example.)*

Comment: Thank you ~ so much ~ . it works . I guess regular ```for``` loop works but not ```map``` .

Comment: @CharlieSiNB - `map` doesn't do anything with the promise your callback returned (other than build a new array containing those promises), it just continues with the next iteration through the array. In general, only pass `async` functions as callbacks when either A) You know that the thing calling the callback understands it if the callback returns a promise, or B) The thing calling the callback stores the return value for you and gives them to you later, and you use the result.

Comment: So it can be useful to use an `async` function with `map`, but only if you want an array of promises (without waiting for any of them to settle). That's handy, for instance, when you want to start a bunch of asynchronous things that will run in parallel and wait for them all to finish (`await things.map(async (thing) => { /*...*/ });`). `map` is almost the only function that doesn't expressly handle promises that it can make sense to pass an `async` function to.